# SwiftUI dismiss after list reorder

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I'm trying to reorder my CoreData items, but when I try reorder items and drop cell my list view is being dismissed. All changes are saved and displayed correctly in other views and in the list that is modified.
Here's my code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DaysOrderView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Days.entity(), sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]) var days : FetchedResults<Days>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(days, id: \.self ) { day in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: day.isDisplayed.boolValue ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "checkmark.circle").foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    Text(day.name)
                }
            }
            .onMove(perform: onMove)
        }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
    }
    
    private func onMove(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
            
        var revisedItems: [ Days ] = days.map{ $0 }
        
            revisedItems.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination )
        
            for reverseIndex in stride( from: revisedItems.count - 1,
                                        through: 0,
                                        by: -1 )
            {
                    revisedItems[ reverseIndex ].id = Int16( reverseIndex )
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you looking to have some arbitrary sort order?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be sorted by id.

Answer (score 0):

An id is not arbitrary, and changing id's to change the sort order can have consequences. If you want a changeable order, I would recommend keeping track of it with an attribute dedicated to the sort order and change that.

I put together a quick app using both a `sortOrder` attribute and an `id` attribute. When I used 'id`as an`Int16` and sorted and changed on that, I got the following error:

> ForEach<FetchedResults, Int16, NavigationLink<Text, Text>>: the
> ID 2 occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give
> undefined results!

Swapping it out for a `sortOrder` attribute gave no errors. Since you didn't, understandably with Core Data, post the entire code, I can't be 100% sure, but I am betting your problem comes down to this issue. Also, you should make your `id` a `UUID()` that is what it exists for, and do not change the id. It is like the parents with multiple kids swapping the kids' names on a daily basis. It might work, but most likely it is chaos.

FWIW the code used to test:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.sortOrder, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item \(item.sortOrder) at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                .onMove(perform: onMove)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            newItem.id = UUID()
            newItem.sortOrder = Int16(items.count)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func onMove(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
            
        var revisedItems: [ Item ] = items.map{ $0 }
        
            revisedItems.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination )
        
            for reverseIndex in stride( from: revisedItems.count - 1,
                                        through: 0,
                                        by: -1 )
            {
                    revisedItems[ reverseIndex ].sortOrder = Int16( reverseIndex )
            }
    }

}
```

It is the base "Use Core Data" code that I added the attributes to.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. View still is dismissing after reorder :/